# Regular expression (RE) in tlmgr search

Tags: tlmgr, perl

https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#search said that

> search
> search [option...] what
>
> search [option...] --file what
>
> search [option...] --all what
>
> By default, search the names, short descriptions, and long descriptions of all locally installed packages for the argument what, interpreted as a (Perl) regular expression.

and *what* could be a Perl re. However how to use it to find packages/collections/schemes with string `a` or `b`? I'vd tried

```bash
tlmgr search a|b
tlmgr search /a|b/
tlmgr search m/a|b/
```

All of them returns

```bash
b: The term 'b' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

So how should I use this action?

My environment is `Win10 20H2`, `TeXLive 2021`, version `58938` of `tlmgr`.

Comment: You probably need to use `'/a/' `

Comment: I used `tlmgr search '/a|b/' ` and still got `'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Hmm, will have a look when at a pc

Comment: literally the string is the regular expression. But in a terminal `|` has special meaning so `tlmgr search a|b` does not work as the terminal interprets it as `send the output from `tlmgr search a` to the program `b`. Try `tlmgr search 'a|b'`, then it is part of a string and is not interpreted by the terminal.

Comment: I still got the same error...:(

Comment: For the sake of it, did you also try `"a|b"` ?

Comment: yeah, I've tried it, the same error.

Comment: According to people in chat `"a|b" ` aka double quotes does work for them on Windows 10. Otherwise please report the problem to the texlive mailing list